# Are the groups$ (\mathbb{R}^\times, \cdot)$ and $((\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}_2), +)$ isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have attempted to find a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^\times$ to $(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}_2)$ but can't seem to get anything to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x\mapsto (x,0)$$
$$-e^x\mapsto (x,1)$$
Gives the isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm just wondering how 0 is mapped in the expression above? Or is there a reason you don't need to consider it?

Comment: Simply, $0\notin\Bbb{R}^\times$. The multiplicative group of real numbers does not contain zero. It has no inverse.

Comment: $0 \not\in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$

Comment: It would improve the Answer to add a few words about how the mapping preserves either inverses or "products" from the domain.

Comment: What would the bijective function actually be in this case?

Comment: @mathsman  what is your question? I defined the function to you. If you want to write it in one line try this $x\mapsto (\log|x|,\sgn(x)$, where the function in the second coordinate gives the signature of $x$, i.e. $0$ if $x>0$, $1$ if $x<0$.